# How do I convert from 3gp to dvd?

Tags: windows, dvd, 3gp

I have some videos recorded on my cellphone that I want to put on DVD so that they can be watched in a standard consumer DVD player.  I've copied the videos from my cell phone to my computer and they have the 3gp file extension.

How to I convert from 3gp to dvd?

Comment: that depends if you want one program to do all of it or you don't mind using couple programs to do the job

Comment: I'm okay with using some toolchain.  If there's something that does it all at once then that would be better, but ultimately I want a quality finished product whatever the process (within reason).

Comment: Then you firstly you could use HandBrake to convert 3gp to dvd and then use burning software to burn the disc.

Comment: Woah just discovered http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ hope that becomes successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, I have used http://www.dvdflick.net/ it is simple and do the job for creating DVDs from video files.

Comment: Yup that's what I ended up using.  I'll mark this the answer after giving it some time to see if any other suggestions come in.

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite popular http://www.my3gpconverter.com/3gp-to-dvd-converter.html there's a trial version not sure how much functionality you get with Trial but if you like you can buy it.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

‘Apparently’ there is also [freemake](http://www.freemake.com/) which, unlike 3GP to DVD Converter is free (so at least fits the bill - of zero - better than Kien’s answer IMO) but may be difficult to use with “personal experience” that 3GP to DVD is much easier – except that the “personal experience” turns out to be just an audit trap (that I failed for trying to improve the “answer” via an edit). Yes it was a short answer – but still longer than the one accepted here.

So **I** have no experience of freemake but it does seem to be another option (and valid as an answer, whether or not correct).